# Kubernetes with Dual Stack on both Pod and Service level

Tags: networking, ipv6, kubernetes, calico

I have 3 Ubuntu VMs where all of them have 2 interfaces. One interface with v4 address and other with both v4 and v6 address. 3 VMs are reachable from each other on all 3 (2 v4 and 1 v6) addresses.

I'm trying to install Kubernetes Cluster with Calico where I need both pod and service IPs should be dual stack supported. I searched and tried a lot - IPv4-only works fine. Any mix of IPv6 fails in kube-proxy, or kube-dns or calico.

I'm posting a question here to ask whether any fellow administrator have installation procedure for kubernetes with IPv6 (Calico).

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what was already done, but you'd start with creating 
your CNI config file `/etc/cni/net.d/10-calico.conf` with enabled dual-stack networking, similar to :

```
{
    "name": "calico-k8s-network",
    "type": "calico",
    "etcd_endpoints": "http://<Your-ETCD>:2379",
    "etcd_ca_cert_file": "/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem",
    "ipam": {
        "type": "calico-ipam",
        "assign_ipv4": "true",
        "assign_ipv6": "true"
    },
    "policy": {
        "type": "k8s"
    },
    "kubernetes": {
        "kubeconfig": "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig"
    }
}`
```

Comment: file? I'm referring to this page https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/getting-started/kubernetes/ for installing calico. It's a pod in my cluster and the calico configuration is in the yaml and not as a file in my master node.

Comment: @RKajaMohideen refer to this step-by-step instuction "IPv6 on CNI side"- https://www.projectcalico.org/enable-ipv6-on-kubernetes-with-project-calico/